# Disconnect idle client in C

Tags: c

I have a list of clients and their descriptors.
First, I would like to start a timer when each client connects to my server.
And my problem is that I want to disconnect clients that are inactive for x seconds (for example 120 seconds).
I just would like to have an idea of how to proceed (or with a code sample)

Comment: One approach is to use `select` with a timeout of 120 seconds. If the `select` times out, then disconnect. If you use a single `select` to handle multiple clients, then you need to need to keep timestamps for the last communication from each client.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of what you've done so far

Comment: In each client structure you need to keep track of the disconnect time. In your main loop (I assume you are using `poll` or `select` or similar) you need to check the *first* disconnect time and use that as the timeout. If the current time is after the disconnect time, then disconnect.

Comment: I agree that using `select` with timeout is a good way to go. But, most servers are multithread/multiprocess and do a `pthread_create/fork` after calling `int fdconn = accept(fdlisten);` [and pass `fdconn` to the service function]. Then, `select` should only need `fdconn`. Otherwise, the server is _single_ threaded and you'd already be using `select` to service multiple clients from a single thread. And, the `select` mask would have to include `fdlisten` as well as all `fdconn` for each active client. The latter is much more complicated to implement, so I'd use the first method.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post your server code in a code block here. If you have a working multithread/multiprocess implementation, adding `select` is just a few lines of code.

Comment: Study [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

Comment: If you don't have an eventloop already (built around select/poll or similar), build one. Then record the time in a struct together with other client info when the client connects. On each iteration of the event loop  read the time, spin through the list of clients and kick out the ones that are older than 120 seconds. (Later on you an start imlementing a timer system which keeps a sorted list of expiry timers around that you run each event loop iteration, so you don't have to check each client every iteration of the event loop)

Answer (score 0):

A method that works independently of the system chosen to listen to the client (`fork`, `pthread`, `select`) is to use `poll` with a timeout, this example works with `stdin` as file descriptor, you just have to adapt it to your environment, basically change:

```
struct pollfd pfd = {.fd = STDIN_FILENO, .events = POLLIN};
```

to

```
struct pollfd pfd = {.fd = fd, .events = POLLIN};
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct pollfd pfd = {.fd = STDIN_FILENO, .events = POLLIN};

    /**
     * poll()
     * Waits for one of a set of file descriptors to become ready to perform I/O.
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Arguments:
     *      1) Pointer to pollfd
     *      2) Number of pollfds
     *      3) Timeout in milliseconds
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Returns:
     *      -1 on error
     *      0 on timeout
     *      Another value if "ready"
     */
    int ready = poll(&pfd, 1, 120000); // 120 seconds

    if (ready == -1)
    {
        perror("poll");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (ready == 0)
    {
        // close(fd);
        puts("Timeout");
        // return from your pthread handler or exit your forked process here
    }
    if (pfd.revents & POLLIN)
    {
        // Handle client here
        // ssize_t size = recv(...); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In each client structure you need to keep track of the disconnect time.

In your main loop (I assume you are using `poll` or `select` or similar) you need to check the earliest disconnect time, calculate how far that is from now, and use that as the timeout. If the earliest disconnect time is 5 seconds after now, then the timeout should be 5 seconds.

If you get a timeout, then disconnect that client.

Optionally you may put the clients in a sorted list based on their timeout so it's easy to find the next one; optionally you may check if more than one client times out at the same time, etc; that's out of scope.